Geojson "MultiLineString" to "LineString"
Is it possible to create a single contiguous LineString from a MultiLineString in a geojson without messing up the geometry of the line?
(Think like messed up MultiLines of roads overlapping and having small gaps also flipped orientation)
This Node JS code does a poor job:
const fs = require('fs');

// Load the GeoJSON data
const geojson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('Route20OK.geojson', 'utf8'));

// Helper function to calculate the distance between two coordinates
function calculateDistance(coord1, coord2) {
    const [lon1, lat1] = coord1;
    const [lon2, lat2] = coord2;
    const R = 6371000; // Earth radius in meters

    const dLat = (lat2 - lat1) * (Math.PI / 180);
    const dLon = (lon2 - lon1) * (Math.PI / 180);

    const a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) ** 2 + 
              Math.cos(lat1 * (Math.PI / 180)) * Math.cos(lat2 * (Math.PI / 180)) *
              Math.sin(dLon / 2) ** 2;

    return R * 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
}

// Step 1: Find the two most "extreme" endpoints
function findExtremeEndpoints(segments) {
    const endpoints = [];

    // Collect all endpoints
    segments.forEach(segment => {
        endpoints.push(segment[0], segment[segment.length - 1]);
    });

    // Calculate a score for each endpoint by summing its distances to all other endpoints
    const scores = endpoints.map((endpoint, i) => {
        let score = 0;
        endpoints.forEach((other, j) => {
            if (i !== j) score += calculateDistance(endpoint, other);
        });
        return { point: endpoint, score };
    });

    // Sort by score and select the top two endpoints as the extreme endpoints
    scores.sort((a, b) => b.score - a.score);
    return [scores[0].point, scores[1].point];
}

// Step 2: Connect segments into a continuous path with orientation checks
function connectSegments(segments, extremeEndpoints) {
    const [extremeStart, extremeEnd] = extremeEndpoints;
    let path = [extremeStart];
    let currentPoint = extremeStart;
    const gapTolerance = 50; // meters

    while (segments.length > 0) {
        let closestIndex = -1;
        let closestSegment = null;
        let closestDistance = Infinity;
        let reverse = false;

        // Find the closest segment to connect to the current path end
        for (let i = 0; i < segments.length; i++) {
            const segment = segments[i];
            const start = segment[0];
            const end = segment[segment.length - 1];

            const distanceToStart = calculateDistance(currentPoint, start);
            const distanceToEnd = calculateDistance(currentPoint, end);

            if (distanceToStart < closestDistance) {
                closestDistance = distanceToStart;
                closestIndex = i;
                closestSegment = segment;
                reverse = false;
            }
            if (distanceToEnd < closestDistance) {
                closestDistance = distanceToEnd;
                closestIndex = i;
                closestSegment = segment;
                reverse = true;
            }
        }

        if (closestSegment) {
            // Reverse the segment if necessary
            if (reverse) closestSegment.reverse();

            // Add segment to the path, projecting midpoint for small gaps
            if (closestDistance <= gapTolerance) {
                const midPoint = [
                    (currentPoint[0] + closestSegment[0][0]) / 2,
                    (currentPoint[1] + closestSegment[0][1]) / 2
                ];
                path.push(midPoint);
            }

            path.push(...closestSegment);
            currentPoint = path[path.length - 1];
            segments.splice(closestIndex, 1); // Remove the segment from the list
        } else {
            break; // Exit if no more segments can connect
        }
    }

    return path;
}

// Process each feature in the GeoJSON
geojson.features = geojson.features.map(feature => {
    if (feature.geometry.type === 'MultiLineString') {
        const segments = feature.geometry.coordinates;

        // Step 1: Identify major endpoints using distance scoring
        const extremeEndpoints = findExtremeEndpoints(segments);

        // Step 2: Connect segments to form a continuous path
        const orderedCoordinates = connectSegments(segments, extremeEndpoints);

        // Update the geometry to a LineString with the ordered coordinates
        feature.geometry = {
            type: 'LineString',
            coordinates: orderedCoordinates
        };
    }
    return feature;
});

// Write the modified GeoJSON to a new file
fs.writeFileSync('Route20Final.geojson', JSON.stringify(geojson, null, 2));

console.log('GeoJSON has been processed and saved to output.geojson');

Link to download geojson

How download "Route20OK.geojson"?

Bench Vue I just added a google drive link to the file

I think you need to broken down code from single giant geometry to multiple geometry.
From

To

demo.js
const fs = require('fs');

const geojson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('Route20OK.geojson', 'utf8'));

// Function to split each segment into separate LineString features
function splitMultiLineString(feature) {
    const segments = feature.geometry.coordinates;
    return segments.map(segment => ({
        type: "Feature",
        properties: { ...feature.properties },
        geometry: {
            type: "LineString",
            coordinates: segment
        }
    }));
}

// Process each feature in the GeoJSON
let newFeatures = [];
geojson.features.forEach(feature => {
    if (feature.geometry.type === 'MultiLineString') {
        // Split the MultiLineString into multiple LineString features
        const lineStringFeatures = splitMultiLineString(feature);
        newFeatures.push(...lineStringFeatures);
    } else {
        newFeatures.push(feature);
    }
});

geojson.features = newFeatures;

fs.writeFileSync('Route20Final.geojson', JSON.stringify(geojson, null, 2));

console.log('GeoJSON has been processed and saved to Route20Final.geojson');

Result by geojson.io


Not sure if you understood my problem. I want a single contiguous line. I want to animate it in After Effects through Geolayers, but it turns out as chunks of paths with different orientation and not in the right order. Although it looks fine on a static map, it's awful for animation

Single geometry with single LineString makes a side effect to add jumping lines between previous geometry  and current geometry. Are you want to accumulate whole lines distance?

Well the script I posted tries to find the nearest endpoints of each nested array, sort, reverse when necessary, account for some small overlaps and gaps, so that the arrays are properly sorted and oriented. But, it doesn't work when the geometry is really bad like in this case the "Route20OK.geojson" file...

Sorry, I don't understand you try to do, I can't help you.
